# ionic capacitor / Xcode error: pspa_proxymap is missing

Tags: xcode, capacitor

i have build many apps before with ionics capacitor.

but this time I am getting an error like:

**Global variable 'pspa_proxymap' missing.**

I never got an error message like this before + I can not find anything here on stack or at google.

any idea? :(

Thx for your help[image]

Comment: And where is it making that variable call?

Comment: @1antares1 Hi, of course it was my fault. I have searched in my Visual Studio Code globally for this variable BUT my case sensitive search option was active so I have thought its something IONIC specific. but now I found out, that it was a variable in the <script> part in my main index.html (src folder). I have added some values to this variable and now the app is running. Thx for your answer. have a good one. bye